# New SSD does not show in Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-format

I wanted to upgrade the internal SSD of my Mid 2013 MacBook Air. I bought a normal M2 SSD and an adapter.

The ssd is not shown by `diskutil ls`. The output of the command is shown in the screenshot.

Could it be, that the SSD is wrongly formatted or is the only possibility that either the adapter or the SSD itself is broken? I could check the SSD with a friend in the next couple of days.

[image]

Also, I am wondering about all the smaller disks shown in the output (disk 2 - disk 11). What are those?

Comment: I've rotated & perspective cropped, but the image is barely legible, far too low rez.

Comment: The SSD does not seem to be properly recognized. Formatting would not matter as the disk would still show up as diskX in both Terminal and Disk Utility (where X is any number, depending on how many storage devices are connected). The fault could be with either the SSD, the adapter, or compatibility issues. (My best guess would be either the adapter or incompatibility).

Comment: What is the last installed system on this Mac?